# Indices of substring

Tags: f#, substring

I am very new to F#. I wrote a function that returns an array of the indices of substring matches in the target and its similar to how I write in C#.

Is there a more functional way of solving this problem, and can it be solved without using any mutable variables?

```
let SubStringIndices (haystack:string) (needle:string) =
    let mutable indices = System.Collections.Generic.List<int>()
    let mutable index = haystack.IndexOf(needle)
    while index >= 0 do
        indices.Add(index)
        index <- haystack.IndexOf(needle, index+1)
    indices.ToArray()

printfn "%A" (SubStringIndices  "abaabababaaab" "ab")
// prints [|0; 3; 5; 7; 11|]
```

I am not looking for a solution which checks for substring match at each index.

Comment: BTW, it is not necessary to make `indices` mutable in this example. This collection type is mutable by itself. By declaring `indices` mutable, you create a mutable reference to a mutable collection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

something like

```
let SubStringIndices (haystack:string) (needle:string) = 
    -1 |> Seq.unfold (fun n -> 
        let idx = haystack.IndexOf(needle, n + 1)
        if idx <> -1 then Some(idx, idx) else None        
        )
```

Comment: it should be Some(idx,idx) .. unfold is what i was looking for, thanks

Comment: Thanks, made a typo while typing directly in browser

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple recursive function that does the same thing:

```
let rec subStringIndices (haystack:string) (needle:string) (from:int) =
  let index = haystack.IndexOf(needle, from)
  if index >= 0 then 
    let rest = subStringIndices haystack needle (index + 1)
    index::rest
  else []

printfn "%A" (subStringIndices  "abaabababaaab" "ab" 0)
```

The function takes an additional parameter `from` that represents the starting index (where you want to start searching in the string). Initially, this is set to zero. In the function, we first get the next index. If we find something, we recursively process the rest of the string (starting from `index + 1`) and return a list containing the index and all recursively obtained indices.

A slightly more elegant and more efficient version that uses *tail-recursion* can be written using the *accumulator parameter* trick and nested function:

```
let subStringIndices (haystack:string) (needle:string) =
  let rec loop (from:int) acc =
    let index = haystack.IndexOf(needle, from)
    if index >= 0 then 
      loop (index + 1) (index::acc)
    else
      List.rev acc
  loop 0 []
```

The recursive looping is now implemented by the `loop` function. It gets `haystack` and `needle` as parameters from the outside, so these don't need to be copied on the stack. We accumulate the indices in the `acc` list passed as parameter and when we reach the end, we return the list (reversed, because we were adding new items to the front).

Comment: but it can't be functional, you didn't use match ... with anywhere! ;)

Comment: @Massif :-) recursion should be good enough! But you could use `match` to test the `index` (it wouldn't make the code any nicer, so I didn't do that)